# Overriding Node.js HTTP parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, shoutcast, internet-radio

I am using Node's basic `http.request()` function without problem on normal HTTP servers.  I need to use `http.request()` (or similar) with SHOUTcast servers.  The SHOUTcast "protocol" is fully compatible with HTTP, except for one detail...  the first response line.

**Normal HTTP servers respond with:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

**SHOUTcast servers respond with:**

```
ICY 200 OK
```

Again, the rest of the protocol is the same.  The only difference is `HTTP/1.x` vs. `ICY`.

I would like to extend, subclass, or somehow modify Node's `http.request()` function so that I can make it work with SHOUTcast servers.  Connecting to SHOUTcast with Node [has been done before](https://github.com/fwg/node-radio-stream), but only by re-inventing the entire wheel.  I'd rather not do that for what amounts to be a minor protocol difference.

### My Question:  Is there a way to do one of the following?

1. **Extend or override** the relevant parts of Node's HTTP parser.  (I doubt this is possible, as it seems [the parser is native code](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/blob/master/http_parser.c#L1057).)
2. **Create my own** bit of code that parses the relevant parts of HTTP, but reuses as many existing Node components for HTTP as possible.
3. **Create a simple internal proxy** (or somehow relay data) so that I can modify that first server response line prior to it reaching Node's HTTP parser.
4. **Something else?**

I have also considered using [Shred](https://github.com/spire-io/shred), but it does not offer an option to stream the response.  (It waits for the entire server response to be complete before firing an event, which won't work for streaming servers where the data can run indefinitely.)  Along those same lines, I tried [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), but it uses Node's own HTTP parser, so I get the same parse errors as I would with the native HTTP client.

Comment: Wow, SHOUTcast looks really bad...

Comment: It was made in a simpler time. :-D

Comment: "fully compatible"... Except for the most popular response code.

Comment: @Joe, The status codes (`200 OK`, etc) are the same.  The only difference is the protocol identification/version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come up with another way to do this, similar to the internal proxy, but without the extra connection.  It seems that it is possible to override the internally used socket for the HTTP client.  When this is done, it is easy to hook in and modify data before passing it off to the original internal socket `ondata` function.

### Usage

```
var httpicy = new HttpIcyClient();
httpicy.request(/* your normal request parameters here */);
```

### Source

```
var http = require('http');

var HttpIcyClient = function () {};
HttpIcyClient.prototype.request = function (options, callback) {
    var req = http.request(options, callback),
        originalOnDataFunction,
        receiveBuffer = new Buffer(0);

    req.on('socket', function (socket) {
        originalOnDataFunction = socket.ondata;
        socket.ondata = function (d, start, end) {
            receiveBuffer = Buffer.concat([receiveBuffer, d.slice(start, end)]);
            if (receiveBuffer.length >= 4) {
                socket.ondata = originalOnDataFunction;
                if (receiveBuffer.toString('ascii', 0, 4) === 'ICY ') {
                    receiveBuffer = Buffer.concat([new Buffer('HTTP/1.0 ', 'ascii'), receiveBuffer.slice(4)]);
                }
                socket.ondata.apply(this, [receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.length]);
            }
        };
    });
    return req;
}
```

Comment: very interesting, didn't know you could do this

Answer (score 1):

> 3 . Create a simple internal proxy

*Bang.* You got it.

Use the [Node.js `net` object](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) to create a TCP server that actually sits between the user and the http server. Replace the first line of all requests and responses as you've described, and you can continue to use http server essentially as-is. (You create an internal http server on a non-standard port, the net server on another port, then chain up streams between the two, with a bit of code to intercept the first chunk of data from the requesting user, and the first chunk of data from the responding server.)

All of your code in Javascript and it's all streaming with (almost) no bufferbloat.

EDIT, it seems I misread your post slightly. I see that you're not trying to implement a Node.js shoutcast server, but trying to access data from it. The `net` object should still work, but not quite in the same way.

You'll need to use `net.connect` to talk to the specified shoutcast server, and use a new `net` server that knows about the `net.connect` stream to proxy between it and your `http.request()`. So, it would work like:

```
+---------------+    +----------+    +-----------+    +----------------+
| http.request()|--->|net.Server|--->|net.connect|--->|SHOUTcast Server|
|               |<---|          |<---|           |<---|                |
+---------------+    +----------+    +-----------+    +----------------+
                  TCP             JS               TCP
```

That's about how I'd structure it.

Comment: Thanks David.  Do you know if there is a way to create a non-network socket and achieve the same effect?

Comment: Not really. The http.request() expects to talk to a TCP stream, and so does the SHOUTcast Server. Since they can't talk directly to one another, you have to proxy with something that takes TCP on either end of the connection to translate between the two. See my updated answer with the ASCII-tacular diagram. :)

Comment: Got it, thanks for your feedback.  I was thinking about doing this earlier but talked myself out of it, due to the extra overhead.  Looking at it again, it doesn't seem that bad.  I'll crack on it tonight.  Thanks!