# Why is server.listen(0) returning a port that another application is listening on?

Tags: node.js, macos

In the Node.js docs for `server.listen`, it states

> If port is omitted or is 0, the operating system will assign an arbitrary unused port, which can be retrieved by using server.address().port after the 'listening' event has been emitted.

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen

However, I've noticed that ports which other applications are listening on are being assigned e.g. ports that Slack and Spotify are listening on.

From looking at a previous question [How does Node.js choose random ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901043/how-does-node-js-choose-random-ports), it appeared that macOS may have just been allocating ephemeral ports sequentially without checking if they were in use. However, running the following script (`index.js`) in a loop (`for i in {1..1000}; do node index.js; done;`) shows the certain ports are being skipped over.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.write("Testing ephemeral port allocation.");
        res.end(); 
      })
      .listen(0, function () {
        console.log(`server is listening on port ${this.address().port}`);
        this.close();
      });
```

It would be great to understand why this is occurring, or if there is anything I'm missing to prevent ports that other applications are listening on from being allocated?

*Background*: I first became aware of this when a *superagent* test suite (using `server.listen(0)`) was randomly failing (*macOS Mojave*, *Node 10*). Tracking down the failures, showed that the tests were failing when the allocated port already had another application listening on it (e.g. Slack and Spotify).

Comment: Can you add some details, e.g. the code that you're using & the output from netstat?